# How two zip two sets into a map in Java

Tags: java, set

I have a Set A:

```
[{name: a,value: 10},
 {name: b,value: 11}]
```

and Set B:

```
[{name: a,value: 100},
 {name: b,value: 110}]
```

Then, I want get Map C:

```
{{name: a,value: 10}:{name: a,value: 100},
 {name: b,value: 11}:{name: b,value: 110}}
```

The key and the the value of each Entry in Map C are equal, which means that the key and the value has the same "name", through different "value"s.
I found guava's Sets is useful, but lack of such functions.

I know this is one way to do that:

```
public static <T> Map<T, T> zip(Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2) {
    Map<T, T> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (T e1 : s1) {
        for (T e2 : s2) {
            if (e1.equals(e2)) {
                map.put(e1, e2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Is there any convenient way to zip two sets in Java?

Comment: Will value1 of SetA always becomes the Key and value1 of SetB becomes the value of MapC? What should happen when there are more Sets? or the 2 Sets are not of identical sizes?

Comment: I upload some code to describe my thoughts.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was some library that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, for this to work override equals and hashcode with field `name`

```
public static <T> Map<T, T> zip(Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2) {
    return s1.stream()
             .filter(s2::contains)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> s2.stream().filter(s -> s.equals(v)).findFirst().get()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The implementation you specified has complexity O(n^2). You can write it as O(n) as follows:

```
public static <T> Map<T, T> zip(Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2) {
    Map<T, T> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (T e1 : s1) {
      T e2 = s2.get(e1) {
         if (e1.equals(e2)) {
            map.put(e1, e2);
            break;
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

This is O(n) because `get()` uses hashing to find the element. For this to work correctly, you need to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` for the actual type passed as `T` to behave properly:

```
class Actual {
  private String name;
  private String value;
  ...
  public int hashCode() { 
    return name.hashCode()
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Actual)) {
      return false;
    }
    Actual other = (Actual)o;
    return name.equals(other.name);
  } 
}
```

Comment: `Set` does not have `get` method